# Agrupar repetições continuas com MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Queria saber se há alguma forma de agrupar repetições usando somente MySQL.

Se fizer um `SELECT * from tabela WHERE id_usuario = 1 ORDER BY id ASC` retornará:

```
id | id_usuario | Data       | Texto
0  | 1          | 2016-10-16 | Sua senha foi alterada
1  | 1          | 2016-10-17 | Sua senha foi alterada
2  | 1          | 2016-10-18 | Sua senha foi alterada
3  | 1          | 2016-10-19 | Sua chave de 2FA foi alterada
4  | 1          | 2016-10-19 | Sua chave de 2FA foi alterada
5  | 1          | 2016-10-20 | Seu acesso foi revogado
6  | 1          | 2016-10-20 | Sua senha foi alterada
7  | 1          | 2016-10-20 | Sua chave de 2FA foi alterada
```

Gostaria que houvesse alguma função que retornasse exatamente:

```
id | id_usuario | Data       | Repetição | Texto
2  | 1          | 2016-10-18 | 3         | Sua senha foi alterada
4  | 1          | 2016-10-19 | 2         | Sua chave de 2FA foi alterada
5  | 1          | 2016-10-20 | 1         | Seu acesso foi revogado
6  | 1          | 2016-10-20 | 1         | Sua senha foi alterada
7  | 1          | 2016-10-20 | 1         | Sua chave de 2FA foi alterada
```

Desta forma removendo as repetições e retornando o número de repetições em "Repetição", que poderia ser gerado como num `count(id) as Repetição`, *isso iria permitir informar que houve mais uma notificação do mesmo tipo e teria como expandir para ver as notificações duplicadas, fazendo uma nova requisição.*

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNT(), DISTINCT e GROUP BY.

Exemplo:

> SELECT id, id_usuario, Data, COUNT(DISTINCT Texto) AS Repeticao, Texto from tabela WHERE id_usuario = 1 GROUP BY id ASC

Comment: Isso irá agrupar tudo e não apenas por repetição. Imagine isto: 1 1 2 1, que cada número seja uma linha. No seu caso resultaria em 3 e 1. Logo, 3 x "1" e 1 x "2"O que eu desejaria seria: 2 x "1", 1 x "2", 1 x "1", sendo então a contagem de 2 1 1. Porque possui 2 vezes o "1" e então é interrompido por um "2" e depois existe um novo "1".

Comment: Troquei o ORDER BY por GROUP BY, assim vai agrupar pelos ids que você quer.